# Laravel and MySQL timestamp value changes with mysqld configuration

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, php-carbon

I have MySQL and Laravel on my local server, with default configuration and my timezone is GMT+2.

### Test 1

I don't touch anything in the MySQL configuration and I try something on my database :

```
SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, UTC_TIMESTAMP;
```

Results:

```
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP       UTC_TIMESTAMP
2020-06-09 16:34:58     2020-06-09 14:34:58
```

Now, I want to request this raw in Laravel:

```
id  device_id   lat        lng          alt     at      created_at               updated_at
1   10          10.000000  10.000000    NULL    NULL    2020-06-09 16:21:55      2020-06-09 16:21:55
```

Here is my test using `php artisan tinker`:

[image: TEST 1]

It shows 16:34 in UTC (GMT+0).

### Test 2

Now I try to change the configuration of mysql (in `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf`), and I set this configuration:

```
default_time_zone='+00:00'
```

I reboot my server:

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

And then I try again the same test than above:

```
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP       UTC_TIMESTAMP
2020-06-09 14:42:46     2020-06-09 14:42:46
```

Now, the raw shows something different (from 16 to 14 hours):

```
id  device_id   lat        lng          alt     at      created_at               updated_at
1   10          10.000000  10.000000    NULL    NULL    2020-06-09 14:21:55      2020-06-09 14:21:55
```

And in Laravel:

[image]

It shows 14:34 in UTC (GMT+0).

### The problem

I was expecting Laravel/Carbon (or maybe MySQL) to understand that the date is still the same but it looks like it doesn't.
Also, with the configuration of the `Test 1`, when a column default to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` Laravel understands it as UTC which is wrong because MySQL will initialize it as GMT+2 (in my case).

For example, when I execute a `INSERT INTO` query on a table (outside of Laravel, from Adminer or PhpMyAdmin) which have a timestamp column `DEFAULT` to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, MySQL will insert "18:00" as GMT+2 while Laravel will read "18:00" as GMT+0.
How can I avoid this problem ? Is setting the mysqld parameter as in `Test 2` is right ?

Answer (score 1):

Converting the timezone of your dates from your database server to your application server is a bad idea. They should work with the **same** timezone, because timezone conversions are not 1:1 conversions due to DST changes. Your local/development environment should be as close as possible as your production environments. And the whole tooling (both DB and Laravel) would better to all be in GMT+00:00 (= "UTC" in Laravel config) so it's UTC-standard based, and you will be able to easily reuse/exchange your data (or a part of it) to an other service/user with any other timezone now or later, timezones like `"GMT+2"` should come only when you want to display a date to a user you know is in this timezone, not for storage.

Answer (score -2):

You need to change the timezone in PHP configuration.

In your php.ini file, change this value -  `date.timezone`

or you can set the timezone in Laravel config.

in your- app/config/app.php - `'timezone' => 'UTC'` change this value.

Comment: Also, my Laravel config was already as you said, I forced `date.timezone = UTC` too but nothing changed after reboot.